# How to Parse Nested / Multiple Json Objects using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, pojo

The JSON I'm parsing looks like this:

```
{   "version": 1
    "data": {
        "1001": {
          "id": 1001,
          "name": "herp",
          "into": [
            "3111": "we"
          ]
        }, 
        "1032": {
          "id": 1002,
          "name": "derp",
          "into": [
            "36": "w",
            "12341: "c"
          ],
          "tags": [
            "hi there"
          ],
          "cost" {
            "even": 15
          }
        }, 
        "1603": {
          "id": 1003,
          "name": "her",
          "into": [
            "37": "dll",
            "58": "eow",
            "32145": "3a"
          ],
          "cost" {
            "highest": 325
            "lowest": 100
          }
        }, 
        .... Even more data
}
```

The Json that is within "data" goes on for a while and does not have a set endpoint. I have no control over the Json, I'm just trying to read it. Unfortunately, with my class code I'm unable to get it to work. When I make a retrofit call the information inside "data" is empty.

I've tried many iterations of implementing this, including using a deserializer and restructuring my POJO code. This is the current state of my Data class:

```
public class Data {

  private Map<String, Item> itemData;

  // Relevant Getters, Setters and Constructors //
}
```

For my Item Class, the main issue is that the JSON Content isn't set, it can vary at times. As you can see above the values inside "into" vary and sometimes the amount of things within item changes as well such as "tags" or "cost":

```
public class Item {

  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String group;
  private String description;
  private Map<String, String> into;
  private List<String> tags;
  private Map<String, Integer> cost;

  // Relevant Getters, Setters and Constructors //
```

When I use this code my data class is empty, I don't see any errors in the log so I can't seem to figure out why the GSON isn't working with this.

In case you wanted to see how I construct my RestClient, here it is:

```
RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(ROOT)
        .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);

RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();
REST_CLIENT = restAdapter.create(DataApi.class);
```

I know that my Rest Query works because I can get the content within "version" but everything inside data is null.

Comment: what does your log say? Class cast exception?

Comment: The log doesn't say anything in regards to an error, is there any way for me to make it more verbose? I already have log level set to full.

Comment: Hm. No exception? Nothing? Have you tried the model structure I've postet as answer?

Comment: Do you have any say over the structure of the JSON that you're receiving? Because it seems like the `into` object should be a map of key-value pairs, not an array as in the example. That way you could handle it with your current implementation.

Comment: @themarshal No I have no control, I'm using an API from somewhere else. In any case I solved the issue if you look below.

Comment: paste your JSON here, http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ , for selective attributes you would get your POJO readymade and you can use that to convert your retrofit response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am officially a dumb scrub and completely looked over the easiest possible fix and should have my account and developer title revoked.

This is all I should have done:

```
public class ItemGroup {

  private String version;
  private Map<String,Item> data;

    //...Man i'm so dumb...
}
```

AS REFERENCE FOR THE FUTURE. The reason why this works is because the JSON is in this format { { } { } { } }. Which means you have 3 objects of objects, as opposed to { [ ] [ ] [ ] } which is 3 objects of a list. What I had done was treat { { } { } { } } as { { { } { } { } } }. Which is not correct. By using a map which is basically a collection of pairs, we are able to imitate the { { } { } { } } with a Map.

Map Object { {Key-Pair Object} {Key-Pair Object} {Key-Pair Object} }

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick idea for your Pojos: 
Not sure if this will work. Maybe write a custom deserializer.

```
public class YourResponse {
    int version;
    Data data;

    class Data {
        Subdata subData;
    }

    class Subdata {
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private ArrayList<Into> into;
        private ArrayList<String> tags;
        //...
    }

    class Into {
        // "3111": "we"
        private String into;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the into class, I want to also keep track of the original String value as well, so would I be able to use a "Pair" class or a "Map" class instead? Also, I assume that I would also need to write extra classes for tags and other random JSON that will pop up inside as well?

Comment: Also, within the Data class, there are multiple instances of subdata, and the JSON doesn't have it as an array, how would I handle that? Thanks for your help, this has been plaguing me.

Comment: Thanks for the help again, helped me think about it some more.